# flutter can't fetch data from api , dio error

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart, dio

So I'm working on a NewsApp and I could successfully manage to fetch data and display it, however the search function wasn't working!
yesterday it just stuck with that error! I've every solution that I came across SOF and git but ended with failure.
I provide images of every related code below. please, help

- base URL: https://newsapi.org/
- method  : v2/top-headlines?
- queries : country=us&category=business&apiKey=65f7f556ec76449fa7dc7c0069f040ca

**for search purpose:**
https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&apiKey=65f7f556ec76449fa7dc7c0069f040ca

> DioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: Failed host lookup:
> 'newsapi.orgv2' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno
> = 7)

[Here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICu8q.jpg)

[dio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKxEJ.jpg)

[cubit code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLxNa.jpg)

[main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS39c.jpg)

## dio code

```
class DioHelper {
  static late Dio dio;

  static init() {
    dio = Dio(
      BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: 'https://newsapi.org',
        receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
      ),
    );
  }

  static Future<Response> getData({
    required String url,
    required Map<String, dynamic> query,
  }) async {
    return await dio.get(
      url,
      queryParameters: query,
    );
  }
}
```

## Cubit code

```
class NewsCubit extends Cubit<NewsStates> {
  NewsCubit() : super(NewsInitialStates());

  static NewsCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);

  int currentindex = 0;
  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> bottomItems = [
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add_business_outlined), label: 'Business'),
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.sports_football_outlined), label: 'Sports'),
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.science_outlined), label: 'Science'),
  ];

  List<Widget> screens = [
    const BusinessScreen(),
    const SportsScreen(),
    ScienceScreen(),
  ];

  void changeBottomNavBar(int index) {
    currentindex = index;
    if (index == 1) getSports();
    if (index == 2) getScience();
    emit(NewsBottomNavState());
  }

  List<dynamic> business = [];

  void getBusiness() {
    emit(NewsGetBusinessLoadingState());
    DioHelper.getData(
      url: '/v2/top-headlines',
      query: {
        'country': 'eg',
        'category': 'business',
        'apiKey': '65f7f556ec76449fa7dc7c0069f040ca',
      },
    ).then((value) {
      // print(value.data['articles'][0]['title']);
      business = value.data['articles'];
      print(business[0]['title']);
      emit(NewsGetBusinessSuccessState());
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e.toString());
      emit(NewsGetBusinessErrorState(e.toString()));
    });
  }

  List<dynamic> sports = [];

  void getSports() {//sports code just like business
  }

  List<dynamic> science = [];

  void getScience() {//science code just like business
  }

  List<dynamic> search = [];

  void getSearch(String value) {
    emit(NewsGetSearchLoadingState());
    search = [];
    DioHelper.getData(
      url: '/v2/everything',
      query: {
        'q': '$value',
        'apiKey': '65f7f556ec76449fa7dc7c0069f040ca',
      },
    ).then((value) {
      // print(value.data['articles'][0]['title']);
      search = value.data['articles'];
      print(search[0]['title']);
      emit(NewsGetSearchSuccessState());
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e.toString());
      emit(NewsGetSearchErrorState(e.toString()));
    });
  }
}
```

## Main class

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  DioHelper.init();
  await CacheHelper.init();

  bool? isDark = CacheHelper.getBoolean(key: 'isDark');

  runApp(MyApp(isDark));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  bool? isDark;
  MyApp(this.isDark);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => NewsCubit()
            ..getBusiness()
            ..getSports()
            ..getScience(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AppCubit()
            ..ChangeAppMode(
              fromShared: isDark,
            ),
        )
      ],
      child: BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppState>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
              floatingActionButtonTheme: const FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
                backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
              ),
              appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
                titleSpacing: 20,
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                // backwardsCompatibility: false,
                systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                  statusBarColor: Colors.white,
                  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 0.0,
                titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              bottomNavigationBarTheme: const BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                selectedItemColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
                elevation: 50,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              textTheme: const TextTheme(
                bodyText1: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            darkTheme: ThemeData(
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: HexColor('333739'),
              primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              floatingActionButtonTheme: const FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
                backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
              ),
              appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                titleSpacing: 20,
                iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                // backwardsCompatibility: false,
                systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                  statusBarColor: HexColor('333739'),
                  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
                ),
                backgroundColor: HexColor('333739'),
                elevation: 0.0,
                titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                selectedItemColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
                elevation: 50,
                backgroundColor: HexColor('333739'),
              ),
              textTheme: const TextTheme(
                bodyText1: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            themeMode:
                AppCubit.get(context).isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
            home: Directionality(
              child: NewsLayout(),
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of your code, post the code itself.

Comment: You need a `/` before your path name eg `/v2/...`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i added / before my path but still give error " DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [429] "
i'll update my question with the codes right now instead of images

Comment: HTTP status 429 means too many requests. Usually this is rate limiting based on user etc so perhaps you should remove your API key from the question and/or regenerate a new one.

Comment: didn't work.. i have set (connectTimeout receiveTimeout sendTimeout) in Dio(BaseOptions) to give more time trying connecting to the server but i got error of "LateInitializationError" late initializing the dio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figure it out> just added connectTimeout, receiveTimeout in my Dio(baseoptions) and it worked for me!

```
class DioHelper {
  static late Dio dio;
  static init() {
    BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: baseUrl,
      connectTimeout: 20 * 1000,
      receiveTimeout: 20 * 1000,
      receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
    );
    dio = Dio(options);
  }

  static Future<List<dynamic>> getData(
      {required Map<String, dynamic> query}) async {
    try {
      Response response =
          await dio.get('v2/top-headlines', queryParameters: query);
      return response.data['articles'];
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return [];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put / after org in your baseUrl

Comment: Could you provide an example of your solution?

Comment: tried that before , and didn't matter at all ....  i posted the answer to my problem, 
thanks for ur involvement btw!